# Deadly Diamond of Death in Coq

Tags: multiple-inheritance, coq, coercion, diamond-problem

I'm trying to create a rather straight-forward type hierarchy. Here's a minimal working example:

```
Record R0 : Type := {
  R0_S :> Type
}.

Record R1 : Type := {
  R1_S   : Type;
  op1    : R1_S -> R1_S
}.

Record R2 : Type := {
  R2_S   : Type;
  op2    : R2_S -> R2_S
}.

Record R12: Type := {
  R12_S   : Type;
  R12_op1 : R12_S -> R12_S;
  R12_op2 : R12_S -> R12_S
}.

Definition R1_0 (r1: R1) := (Build_R0 (R1_S r1)).
Coercion   R1_0 : R1 >-> R0.

Definition R2_0 (r2: R2) := (Build_R0 (R2_S r2)).
Coercion   R2_0 : R2 >-> R0.

Definition R12_1 (r12: R12) := (Build_R1 (R12_S r12) (R12_op1 r12)).
Coercion   R12_1 : R12 >-> R1.

Definition R12_2 (r12: R12) := (Build_R2 (R12_S r12) (R12_op2 r12)).
Coercion   R12_2 : R12 >-> R2.  (* Warning *)
```

That last coercion generates the following warning:

```
Ambiguous paths:
[R12_2; R2_0] : R12 >-> R0
[R12_2; R2_0; R0_S] : R12 >-> Sortclass
R12_2 is now a coercion
```

Indeed, the coercion from `R12` to `R0` (or `Sortclass`) can take two different paths. And I understand why Coq would disallow this in the general case. Because... which of them would be used?

However, in this case it can be shown that the coercion by both paths `R1_0 (R12_1 r12)` and `R2_0 (R12_2 r12)` is exactly the same. But still I'm not able to add the following seemingly valid axioms:

```
Parameter r12 : R12.
Parameter x : r12.
Axiom id1 : (op1 _ x) = x.  (* OK    *)
Axiom id2 : (op2 _ x) = x.  (* Error *)
```

**Question:** So is there a way to convince Coq that this is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no way of convincing Coq that this is OK. However, you achieve a similar effect by using other features, such as canonical structures or type classes. This is how one could translate your example with type classes, for instance:

```
Class R1 T :=
{
  op1 : T -> T
}.

Class R2 T :=
{
  op2 : T -> T
}.

Class R12 T `{R1 T} `{R2 T} :=
{}.

Section S.

Context T `{R12 T}.
Variable x : T.

Hypothesis id1 : op1 x = x.
Hypothesis id2 : op2 x = x.

End S.
```

Notice that class `R12` doesn't have any methods of its own, but requires type `T` to be an instance both of `R1` and `R2`, which results morally in the same thing. The `Context` declaration forces Coq to assume instances for `R1` and `R2` automatically, in virtue of those requirements.

Edit:

If you try to add an `R0` class to complete the diagram, you may get a weird error resulting from a failing type-class inference. One solution is to turn off the automatic generalization in `R12` (i.e., remove the back quotes), and force `R1` and `R2` to be based on the same `R0` instance:

```
Class R0 (T : Type) := {}.

Class R1 T `{R0 T} :=
{
  op1 : T -> T
}.

Class R2 T `{R0 T} :=
{
  op2 : T -> T
}.

Class R12 T `{R0 T} {r1:R1 T} {r2:R2 T} :=
{}.

Section S.

Context T `{R12 T}.
Variable x : T.

Hypothesis id1 : op1 x = x.
Hypothesis id2 : op2 x = x.

End S.
```

Unfortunately, I don't really have a good explanation to why an error could occur there, as type class inference is somewhat complex. However, I think it is not related to the problem you had had first, because there aren't actually ambiguous paths like before.

Comment: But you appear to have removed the base of the diamond (`R0`). That would work for `Record`s too. If I try to add a `Class R0 (T: Type) := {}.` to your hierarchy -- and 'enhance' `R1` and `R2` accordingly -- you get an error at `id1`. A different kind of error than before but, I believe, based on the same problem.

Comment: Hm... It seems that simply putting a member such as `e: T` inside the definition of `R0` makes everything type-check again. --- Anyway, if you could augment your example and explain this strange phenomenon I'd greatly appreciate it! :-)

Comment: There, I just found how to add `R0` to the diagram!

Comment: Yep, I've since come up with a different solution, but it seems to come down to the same thing. Thanks! :-)